# MySQL: 'Product' can belong to multiple groups?

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL `products` table there is a column called groups which products can belong to. What is actually stored in this column are id's of another tabled called `groups`.

What if I want to select products that belong to a specific group?

If a product can only belong to a single group, I could simply use

```
where group={groupid}
```

But what if a product can belong to multiple groups?

I could store them like this: '**4,8,10,42**', each of these numbers meaning a `group` id.
But then how would I query a select?

Comment: Why not making another table called `groups` that will hold all relations between product and groups? That way you will have  a more simpler Database Design for that part..

Comment: You should create a new table in which you store which product belongs to which groups. In it you only have the primary key, the product id and an the group id. That makes it easy lookup all the groups. This is called "normalizing" and is in generall a pretty nice thing. :)

Comment: You might want to read about normalization: http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not store a list of products in a single field. Instead of a column `products.groups`, you should have a separate table `product_groups (product_id, group_id)`, where you store each association between a product and a group. Then you can select all products from a group as this:

```
SELECT product.*
FROM product_groups
INNER JOIN products ON (products.id = product_groups.product_id)
WHERE product_groups.group_id = :group_id`
```

Comment: I thought of doing it like that. But I'm so lazy I thought there might be some easier way. Thanks!

Comment: This is actually the easier way, compared to your initial approach.

Answer (score 2):

Database structure is the one you have to watch in here
if you want a product to have multiple groups, you have to create a third table that products and groups connect to. Then all you have to do is put the product id mapped to the group id

In case the product belongs to only one group it will have only one entry in this table, but if it belongs to multiple groups then it will have (eventually) multiple entries

Answer (score 2):

> I could store them like this: '4,8,10,42',

No, please do **not** do that!

There is a completely well-known, standard, efficient and well tested best practice for creating many-to-many relationships, called a [join table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). Here's how to represent that product 1 is a member of groups 4, 8, 10 and 42 using a join table:

```
product_group
product    group
1          4
1          8
1          10
1          42
```